# Data Context Object in Meteor-Blaze

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I'm failing to understand what is a **Data Context Object** in Meteor-Blaze. Can someone explain what is a **Data Context Object** in Meteor-Blaze? I've searched in the internet yet I couldn't find any proper answers. I'm new to Meteor Blaze please help me...Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Can you please tell, where you read about the data context object? Is it named in the documentation somehere?

Comment: I read it in the blaze documentation..I'm adding the URL . http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html